# Pandas Datetime Manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a pandas dataframe storing units of time:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
      'analysis_datetime': ['2018-07-15 11:50:48+00:00', '2018-07-15 13:22:24+00:00'], 
      'processing_duration': [4930, 8101], 
      'accessioning_duration': [1032, 2310]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Columns `processing_duration` and `accessioning_duration` are in minutes.

I would like to create a new column called `shipping_datetime` based on the following formula:

```
shipping_datetime = analysis_datatime - processing_duration - accessioning_duration
```

The first shipping_datetime should be

```
from datatime import datatime, timedelta

shipping_datetime = datetime.strptime('2018-07-15 11:50:48+00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z') 
- timedelta(minutes=4930) 
- timedelta(minutes=1032)

shipping_datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
```

`'2018-07-15 11:50:48+0000'`

That's one row. I would like to create a new column that applies this to all rows.

Here's what I have so far:

```
df['shipping_datetime'] = df.apply(lamba x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z'): 
pd.to_datetime(x.analysis_datetime) 
- timedelta(minutes=x.processing_duration) 
- timedelta(minutes=x.accessioning_duration), axis=1)
```

I get an invalid syntax error. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise against python's `datetime`. Instead, you should use Pandas' `datetime` to handle time-like Pandas Series. For example you can do:

```
duration = df[['processing_duration','accessioning_duration']].sum(1)

pd.to_datetime(df['analysis_datetime']) - pd.to_timedelta(duration, unit='min')
```

Output:

```
0   2018-07-11 08:28:48+00:00
1   2018-07-08 07:51:24+00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```